# Шампанское(,) и свечи(,) и музыка весь вечер, весь вечер под Новый год

Tags: запятые

Как правильно этот отрывок из песни «Новый год» М. Боярского оформить? Я думаю, что второй вариант верным является, так как *шампанское и свечи* — это как бы вместе.

> Шампанское и свечи, и музыка весь вечер, весь вечер под Новый год.

> Шампанское и свечи и музыка весь вечер, весь вечер под Новый год.

> Шампанское, и свечи, и музыка весь вечер, весь вечер под Новый год.

Comment: Верен первый и третий вариант. Я не слушал. Смотря что вы считаете "вместе" или что автор считает "вместе".

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101 6-й и 8-й пункт можете почитать.

Comment: Тогда второй вариант правильный.

Comment: Нет, второй не подходит.